# Google Chrome: Can't create new page/app shortcuts after updating to v118

Tags: google-chrome

I used to be able to create app shortcuts (i.e. make a web page look like a desktop app) by going to the Chrome menu > "More tools" > "Create shortcut" > "✔️ Open as window". After that, a webpage would appear as a shortcut or alias that I could pin to my OS's dock, and it would also shoud up in chrome://apps .

I got upgraded to v118 today and the feature seems to be gone. Has it moved? If so, where did it go? If not, did it get removed from Chrome?

Here's a screenshot of where this used to appear, but is no longer there. This was taken on v118.0.5993.89 on Windows.

[image: Screenshot of the missing 'Create Shortcut' option]

Comment: It's still there on my side using version 118.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the option moved under "Save and Share" in the Chrome menu:

[image: The "Save and Share" menu option, with "Create a shortcut"]